# referrer in segment.io analytics.page() in a SPA

Tags: analytics, domdocument, referrer

I am trying to integrate [segment.io](https://segment.com/) to work with Angular. My angular app is a SPA so I have to add some code to my components to allow segment to register the page visits.

In the code used to register page visits, there is a property called `referrer` that, [according to the docs](https://segment.com/docs/connections/spec/page/#properties) is:

> Full URL of the previous page. Equivalent to [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer) from
> the DOM API.

The problem I am having is the referrer property value sometimes just remains empty, or sticks to one page even if I move to several other different pages.

So my questions are:

1. Does referrer mean links outside my app or also the previous routes visited within my app?
2. Am I supposed to set this manually in the app?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you're supposed to set it manually in your existing pageview hits to Segment.

Basically, in your case, referrer would be just the previous route. If the previous route doesn't exist, then use the document.referrer.

And yes, organically, if your app doesn't have a previous route, then document.referrer may contain an outside url, which is completely fine and expected.

Also, Segment provides pretty neat support for questions like this, so you can confirm with them.